# Secure way to deploy a Laravel 5 Application on Windows Machine with Internet Connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Currently I have developed a finance system for a client and he wants me  to deploy it on his 'server'.

The "Server" is a computer with **windows 7** installed and the system is supposed to be accessed on a **LAN**.

For now, I have deployed the system on **XAMPP**. I know that the XAMPP, WAMPP, etc. packages aren't very secure, So I created a password for **PhpMyAdmin**, **XAMPP**  page and **MySql**.

I have read many resources stating xampp can be more secured by installing it on a computer with no direct internet access and only allowing access from the local computer (no network access), but as you can understand, the system has be to accessed on the LAN and there will be internet access to the server.

I've also read about deploying it on a **Linux VM**.

**So considering the above situation, here are my questions:**

1. What is the most secure way to deploy a laravel or any php application that will be accessed over a LAN on a windows machine with internet connection?

I understand that security is a vague word because it depends on the system administrator or computer user. I just want to make it as secure as possible on my part (deployment), but the overall security will rest on the computer's condition (Anti-virus, Firewall and other things). I just want to know If i'm using the wrong tools or not. Are there better tools? If there aren't, are there additional ways of making it more secure.

Comment: Start by defining "secure". Given that any single one mistake may open up a security hole which may bring down the entire system, I'd start by not using a standard run-of-the-mill desktop Windows system, which may or may not have a ton of services running, each one of which is a security liability. Is the client also using that computer for browsing porn at night? Who knows...

Comment: :) who know. But the server is on a company LAN.  I know that we can't control every aspect of the users actions and ultimately, his actions will play the biggest role in security. I just want to make sure there are no problems on my part, deployment or code. I'm asking how to make the deployment more secure.

Comment: So are you suggesting i continue with xampp and make more security modifications to it?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is more like a network question, and i am supposing that there are no security threats from the office staff (like someone just cloning your hard drive or copying data physically) and you just want to secure it from the internet.

If i was in your position and was paranoid enough :)

1. In the code i would check if the requests are actually coming for the range of IP addresses the network is using and only show content if that is the case.
2. Secondly i would block all the system ports except the ones used for LAN communication.
3. i would install a great antivirus/firewall with upto date virus database (**i like kaspersky total
   security**).
4. I would only give permissions to certain lan computers to connect to
   the system.
5. Wont use that system for anything other than using it as a server (thats why people use command line linux so it doesn't have a simple gui and make it difficult for a non tech person to get into)
6. Remove all monitors input devices or if possible disable **usb ports and cd/dvd** drives so no one can use a live discs to get into the system.
7. Do regular **physical backups** on dvd drives

Answer (score 0):

Never done this (on Windows), but think can be achieved.

You need SSH and Git.

Bare repository on the working dir

Then, use Git Deploy Post-Receive Hook

Voilá, every time you push to this repository, it will update all the source code, matter of (mili)seconds!

Comment: Don't know who gave me negative comment, but the question was on how to securely deploy, and not how to secure the server, generally!